How to account for clustering in Conditional Logistic Regression in R
I'm playing around with some data obtained for a case-crossover study, where participants serve as their own controls multiple times (matched controls to cases). This data is a bit different from conventional case-crossover studies because participants can also be cases multiple times. For instance, one individual can have 6 data points, where they are cases 3 times and controls 3 times. Because of this, we suspect some form of clustering effect occurring for each participant.
From my understanding, this clustering can be accounted by introducing a clustered standard error in the conditional logistic regression model.
Is there a way to do this in the clogit function in the survival package in R, or perhaps a different package can be utilized?
Thank you for your help!
It seems that this could be easily down in STATA: https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1346488-conditional-logistic-with-clustering, but I have yet to see a solution/method to this specifically for R.
